# Pinterest pin functionality is not working

Tags: pinterest

We are using simple SAVE pin functionality but it is not working. Please click on below url and try to pin it.

https://www.wellmark.com/blue/recipes/main-dishes/hearty-beef-and-butternut-squash-bowl

It seem to me that this is happening due to image but not quite sure why.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https%3a%2f%2fwww.wellmark.com%2fblue%2frecipes%2fmain-dishes%2fhearty-beef-and-butternut-squash-bowl&amp;description=Hearty+beef+and+butternut+squash+bowl&amp;media=https%3a%2f%2fwww.wellmark.com%2f-%2fmedia%2fsites%2fblue-magazine%2f2018-print-editions%2ffall%2frecipe_hearty_beef_butternut_squash_bowl.jpg" target="_blank"><span class="sr-only">Pinterest share</span><span class="icon-pinterest"></span></a>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately this isn't enough info. We're going to see some code attempt and where it's broken so we can help.

Comment: looks like you attempted to share a code snippet, maybe try that again.

Comment: Code is very simple and straightforward. You can also view code by inspecting "pinterest icon" in chrome debugger.